# Inverse function of $x-\lfloor x \rfloor $ and $(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, inverse-function

I need to find the inverse of these two functions if they exist:

$$f_1 = x-⌊x⌋, 1\leq x<2, 0\leq f_1<1$$ and
$$f_2 = (x-⌊x⌋)^2, 1\leq x<2, 0\leq f_2<1$$

I worked through it and I think they are both bijective functions, but I am not exactly sure, and Having trouble finding the actual inverse function for both these two.
Do these two have inverse functions and how do you find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $1\leq x < 2$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is always the same number for all those $x$'s. If you write this number instead of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ in your formulas, you'll get two easy-to-invert functions.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

$f_1(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is called the fractional part function. It returns the value after the decimal point in $x$, and is denoted as $\{x\}$. Note that while $f_1(x)$ is many-one over $\Bbb R~(f_1(x+1)=f_1(x))$, its restriction to $[1,2)$ is injective and onto over $[0,1)$.

In the given domain, $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$, so that $f_1(x)=x-1$. The inverse of this is easily calculated as $f_1^{-1}(x)=y+1,0\le y<1$. Similarly, the inverse of $f_2(x)=\{x\}^2=(x-1)^2$ is $f_2^{-1}(x)=1+\sqrt y,0\le y<1$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and answer :)